# How to bind an event to the group of links in AHAH-requested HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, httpwebrequest

I have an AHAH-requested HTML, like:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td><img src="..." onClick="get_next_ahah(sell####)" id="sell####"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td><img src="..." onClick="get_next_ahah(sell####)" id="sell####"/></td>
</tr>
... and so on
```

where #### - numerical IDs from DB.
How can I replace the function "`get_next_ahah()`" on efficient event-written jQuery function? And how can I find out which id I use?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's like experts-exchange (minus the suck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a rather obscure form of CSS selector to grab all elements whose ID contains the text "sell" and then use that to assign events to them:

```
$("[id^=sell]")
```

Or, if the elements are all guaranteed to be `img`s, you can use this more specific selector instead:

```
$("img[id^=sell]")
```

These selectors will both return an array of elements that have "sell" in the ID, which you can call `click()` on.

To find out the current ID, you can just strip "sell" from the ID and then pass that to your `get_next_ahah()` function, like this:

```
$("img[id^=sell]").click(function() {
    get_next_ahah(this.id.replace('sell', '');
});
```

Comment: @htw - +1, funky way of doing it, but note that attribute filters are sloooow.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to extract the number from the ID if you separated the number from the prefixed string with an underscore or such, e.g.:

```
<img src="..." id="sell_1234"/>
```

Then you would just have to do this:

```
$('table tr td img').click(function() {
    var num = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    get_next_ahah(num);
});
```

If you can't change the ID, then just use a regex instead to extract the number from the string, e.g.:

```
$('table tr td img').click(function() {
    var num = $(this).attr('id').match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1];
    get_next_ahah(num);
});
```

Comment: "Also note that you have closed anchor tags, but no opening ones in your markup"

sorry, changed
Thank you for your Answer